# Selichot on Yom Kippur

Tags: minhag, yom-kippur, selichot

Although quite many machzorim omit it, but there are lengthy selichot composed for all services on Yom Kippur. Is it only an Ashkenazi custom?

Comment: A yekkishe shul recited a selection of Selichos where they were not in the Machzor. My present shul does not.

Comment: No, it's a universal custom. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85353/759

Comment: Does anyone know the mizrachi practice for example?

Answer (score 1):

ב"נ I will post here the selichot of different communities that I find.

**Italian rite**

Angelo Piattelli posted [on his site](https://www.angelopiattelli.com/prayer-books-) the full set of Italian machzorim he edited with R. Hillel Sermoneta based on the Roman tradition that is in use in Jerusalem. In the [Yom Kippur machzor](https://docs.wixstatic.com/ugd/8cabfe_8e0f416d4dbd431fbedc438a104b61e2.pdf) one may find all the selichot, in particular (page numbers according to PDF):

- Maariv: p. 93
- Shacharit: p. 247
- Minchah: p. 476
- Neilah: p. 518

**Livorno rite**

The Spanish and Portuguese communities had a machzor from 1821 translated by Lazzaro Emanuele Ottolenghi.

- Shacharit: [p. 218](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46179&st=&pgnum=218)
- Musaf: [p. 128](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46177&st=&pgnum=128)
- Minchah: [p. 96](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46178&st=&pgnum=96)
- Neilah: [p. 182](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46178&st=&pgnum=182)

**Aram Tzova rite**

The Aleppo community from Syria had a very special set of selichot for Yom Kippur that survives in the [Aram Tzova Machzor](http://www.zomet.org.il/eng/?CategoryID=160&ArticleID=7350) from 1527.

- Vigil: [p. 281](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21965&st=&pgnum=281)
- Shacharit: [p. 323](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21965&st=&pgnum=323)
- Neilah: [p. 366](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21965&st=&pgnum=366)

Comment: What's "Vigil"?

Comment: @Heshy I was trying to find out what this אשמורת צום כפור could be, and I've found a possibly similar Yemenite minhag to get up very early and say these selichot. Do you have in mind a better word for that?

Comment: No it's a great word, I just had no idea what it refers to in context.  But it's really logical to get up early and say selichos on YK the same as you've been doing the last month (for Sefardim at least.. no idea what Teimonim do).  I think I've seen the אשמרת used for the morning selichos during the Yamim Noraim.  Paraphrasing from memory, it was something like "ובערב ר"ה אין אומרים תחנון, רק באשמרת הסליחות אומרים אע"פ שנמשכו הסליחות כמה שעות לתוך היום"