# Adding the 13 middot during / after the Chatanu Selichot on Yom Kippur

Tags: yom-kippur, selichot

Originally, Minhag Ashkenaz was to recite *selichot*, accompanied by the 13 *middot*, during *chazarat hashatz* of all prayers of Yom Kippur. For various reasons, the vast majority of congregations today omit them in *shacharit*, *musaf* and *mincha*, and most of the commonly-printed *machzorim* print no *selichot* in these prayers. (See e.g. [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85352/selichot-on-yom-hakkipurim) for further discussion.) These *selichot* are recited after *ya'aleh veyavo*, and are followed by *zechor rachamecha* (which is printed in *machzorim*).

Consider a synagogue that wishes to recite the 13 *middot*, but does not want to publish separate booklets / handouts of *selichot* to be recited. One possible solution would be to recite the 13 *middot* in conjuction with (either during or immediately following) the *'chatanu' selichot*, which are said after *zechor rachamecha* and before *zechor lanu berit avot* and which do appear in the *machzorim*. This has the advantage of allowing congregants to use only their *machzor*, without needing a separate source for additional *piyutim*.

Are there any sources discussing the legitimacy / advisability of such a practice? I note that classically, the 13 *middot* would only be recited before *zechor rachamecha*, but is there any problem doing so afterwards?

Comment: Tangentially, it seems to me that the '*chatanu' selichot* of *shacharit* and *musaf* would have been followed by *kel melech* and the 13 *middot* at some point in their histories, given that the last phrase of each *piyut* is קל מלך יושב על כסא רחמים.

Comment: Without addressing your technical questions, it seems simplest to just move that piyut back a few pages. Announce, skip to page X, continue back on page Y

Comment: (Side note, chatanu poems were written for recitation during tachanun after the amida. When people stopped saying tachanun on YK they moved them back to some convenient place towards the end of the slichot section. Re your first comment, these examples probably weren't originally chatanu poems, or at least the last lines were appended to chatanu poems.)

Comment: https://www.maimonidesminyan.org/uploads/1/7/2/3/17235610/slichot_for_yom_kippur.pdf